# Calculating the number of operations in an algorithm

Tags: algorithm-analysis

I just started working on algorithms and am having some trouble understanding how you can correctly analyze the number of operations of computations that are done.

According to the [paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7368584/) I am reading, the following two steps take 3 multiplications and 2 exponentiations.

$$m' = m \cdot \frac{P}{p_k} \cdot (P^{-1}\mod p) \mod n^2$$

$$\mathcal{E}(m')=g^{m'} \cdot r^n \cdot h^{n-a}\mod n^2$$

I am not really sure if I am understanding this incorrectly, but I would suspect that, since you see at least 3 exponents, these operations must take at least 3 exponentiations? That same for the multiplication signs, I see at least 4, so how can this be reduced to 3?

Comment: Most likely some of those values can be pre-calculated (calculated once and then re-used).